# How to run arm lib in the Android-x86 5.0

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, android-x86

Under the Android-x86 5.0 system I need to put the arm lib into the x86 lib content and it will be normally System.loadlibrary.
 Seems like houdini has been abandoned after 5.0. What shall I do? 
(I tried hook dlopen and called the function in houdini, but I still couldn't load libdvm_houdini.so)

Answer (score 0):

Binary translation is still there on x86 OEM devices running Android 5.0+, but it's operating on libs that are inside arm folders, not those inside x86. So don't put arm libs inside the lib/x86 folder.

If you don't have x86 versions of your binaries, remove your x86 folder (that's sad, btw).

Comment: may I inquire more details about binary translation on the Android x86 5.0+ ?

Comment: If you have specific questions, maybe I can answer some. Otherwise you can look for "NativeBridge" inside the aosp to see how it's implemented for the OS and apps.

Comment: I have to let Android load x86 lib,because I need to hook some API. can I open arm libs by nativebridge in the x86 lib?  thank you very much.

Comment: You can't do that as the NativeBridge isn't publicly exposed. You can use only arm libs or only x86 libs.